# All tags on the main ux.se site have become unlinked from their questions.

Tags: support, tags

All of the tags come up with '0 Questions Tagged with this Tag' message. It works correctly here on Meta but not on the Main site.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are on the wrong tab. Our tabs are sticky. Can you look again?

Comment: No, still a problem. On the main site I click any of the tags against any question and it opens up the 'Tagged Questions' tab, but shows the message "0 questions tagged". I do the same thing here on Meta and I get a list of several questions tagged with that tag.

Comment: @jon No repro at all on my end. Can you humor me and try clicking different tabs in the question list?

Comment: Jeff - I saw the same thing as Jon. It was taking you to the "Featured" version of the page from the home page. I clicked on "Questions" and it took me to the "Featured" questions. I then clicked on "Newest" and went back to the home page. Clicking on a tag again now took me to the proper page results (showing tags). Looks like the tags page is remembering that I had last viewed the "Featured" view for the questions page and carried it over to the tags page (which doesn't actually show in the sub-nav).

Comment: Yes, Charles is right. I was being taken to the Featured questions tab even though I chose a tag against one of the questions on the main front page. I've now chosen a tag from the Featured tag, and this seems to have fixed the tags for the Main questions section for me. If I can find the re-creation steps for it getting out of line I will post that here.

Answer (score 0):

I have some recreation steps here:

1. Select Questions/Featured
2. Now return to the main screen via the
   UX logo
3. Choose one of the Tags against any
   question
4. This takes you to the 'Featured'
   questions page for the tag selected
   (i.e. nothing).

This also happens on the Meta site: if the last section in the Questions section you visited was the FAQ then choosing any tags from the front screen will only show you the tags for the FAQ section.

As it doesn't actually show you that the 'Featured' tab is the currently active one (it's not even displayed in the tab list) then you can't easily change to the 'Active' tab.

[image: Screenshot]